# What is the attitude towards 'general', chatty questions with no possibility of a 'proper' answer?

Tags: discussion

Like this one: ['Looking for a hardware project idea that actually sells'](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1705/looking-for-a-hardware-project-idea-that-actually-sells).

It reminds me of [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) Vs [Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I also posted a couple of them here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/metawhat-part-of-the-world-are-you-from http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2633/metatell-something-about-yourself I think moving them to meta would be a good idea

Comment: This question (on meta) is of a similar vein: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21/, and has additional information.

Answer (score 4):

A question that asks essential "I need ideas... go!" without any background, or qualifications, or criteria, or anything is--as you say--just being chatty. It's not a good question.

The *answers* suggest that there *could* have been an interesting question in there somewhere but the answers don't match the question. That supports attitude that it is a poorly-conceived question: the answers don't apply because the question is too vague.

[This blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/), while not directly applicable to this case, *might* be helpful in routing out "bad subjective" questions like this.